# Replacing Not In clause in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table #allocations
which has the following fields

```
DAllocationId   DAllocationName FundCode    DSplitTotal DDisabled   DistAlloc   AAllocationId AAllocationName   ASplitTotal ADisabled
```

I have another table TRAN_POST_PTN which also has these columns along with other columns.
So for asplit id and dsplit id we just have the same column name which is "posting number" in TRAN_POST_PTN.

What i need to do is insert into my allocations table all the rows from TRAN_POST_PTN where the

```
posting_number is not in (select DAllocationId from #allocations) 
and posting_number not in (select AAllocationId from #allocations)
```

I do not want to use Not in here.

Can some one please suggest me a better way of writing this query.
I tried writing it using union,but that did not  work.

Comment: What is your RDBMS?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?

Comment: **Why** you don't want to use `not in`?

Comment: Its sql server and why i do not want to use not in,the reason is that it is less efficient as i read on the internet coz for every posting number it will go through all the rows of allocations table.so for n postings numbers in worst case their will be N*N checkings done.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user3408151 I don't know where you read that, but it's just not true. You can check multiple sources ([**here is one**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)) where you can see that normally `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are the best options on performance. The one caveat with `NOT IN` is that you need to be careful with `NULL` values

Comment: @user3408151 - have you actually *measured* the performance of the query and does it actually need to be improved? Performance tuning by "some guy on the internet told me not to use feature X" rarely actually achieves anything useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple alternatives to `NOT IN`.  Here's one using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT fields
FROM TRAN_POST_PTN tpp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #allocations a 
    WHERE tpp.posting_number IN (a.DAllocationId, a.AAllocationId))
```

---

Another common way is to use `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` checks, but I believe you'll see a better performance with `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT fields
FROM TRAN_POST_PTN tpp
    LEFT JOIN #allocations a ON tpp.posting_number = a.DAllocationId 
         OR tpp.posting_number = a.AAllocationId
WHERE a.DAllocationId IS NULL
```

Comment: well again some where in your query u again used IN Operation.I do not want IN or NOT in OPERTAIONS.

Comment: @user3408151 -- I have no clue what you're talking about.  Using IN in this case is to group the `DAllocationId` and `AAllocationId` together.  It's just acting as `OR`...  The problem with your query is not the use of `NOT IN`, but it's that you have to do it twice!

Comment: @sgeddes Don't you get it, man?, `IN` and `NOT IN` are the devil!, some dude on the internet said so, how dare you use them on your answer?

Comment: @Lamak -- LMAO :D But, but, the devil made me do it!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions people,i should have researched some more about it before coming to any conclusions.Thank you for your advice, and Lamak i will make sure not to call IN AND NOT IN as devil and will use them where ever required

Comment: @sgeddes You are missing a parenthesis on the first query. And `;` on both ;)